# React child component receiving different props from what is passed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component `List`, which takes in props and renders a list. It has a prop named `onReorder`, which is a callback function passed from the parent, and is called when the list header is clicked.

`List.js`

```
const List = ({ title, size, columns, data, length = 10, showIndex, onReorder }) => {
    console.log(data)
    return (
        // ... render list 
        <ListHeader onClick={onReorder}>Some Header Text</ListHeader>
    )
}
```

`data` is a 2d array.

When `onReorder` is called, it sorts `data` and calls `setData` to update the order of the array.

`Parent.js`

```
const onReorder = (newOrder) => {
    setData(sortData(data, newOrder))
}

// ...
return (
    <List 
        // key={ MD5('list' + JSON.stringify(order)) } // to ensure that the list is rendered
        size="col-12" length={ 10 } showIndex
        title={ <>Title</> } 
        columns={ listColumns }
        data={ data }
        onReorder={ onReorder }
    />
)
```

**This worked well**, until I tried to map data for some styling:

```
return (
    <List 
        // key={ MD5('list' + JSON.stringify(order)) } // to ensure that the list is rendered
        size="col-12" length={ 10 } showIndex
        title={ <>Title</> } 
        columns={ listColumns }
        data={ data.map(d => [
            <Link to={`/d/${ d[6] }`}>{ d[0] }</Link>,
            d[1],
            <HealthIndicator level={ d[2] }/>,
            <Temperature>{ d[3] }</Temperature>,
            <Status enabled={ d[4] } />,
            d[5]
        ]) }
        onReorder={ onReorder }
    />
)
```

When I press on the header, `onReorder` does fire, and the list is sorted (made sure by console logging). Moreover, the `console.log(data)` in `List` showed the *not-updated* `data`.

I also tried console logging directly in the `data.map(d => {console.log(d); ...})`, and it is showing the correct order, while the `console.log(data)` in `List` is still the previous one.

I also tried changing the `data.map()` to `data.map(d => d)`, which shouldn't change anything, but it still shows the wrong order in `List`.

**So to summarize**, this works:

```
data={ data }
```

but this doesnt:

```
data={ data.map(d => d) }
```

The only reasons I could think of are:

1. Array is sending address instead of value.

- I tried copying the array with `data=[...data]`, didn't do the job.

2. Child is not rendering.

- I tried adding a unique key (as shown above), which still didn't fix the problem. Also, console.log(data) is being called in `List`.

I have already tried everything in my mind and spend hours looking into this and I'm running out of options. Any thoughts or advice is appreciated. I'll provide more code and description if the above code is insufficient.

Thanks in advance :(

Comment: can you post a sample of data?

Comment: @Apostolos A row would be something like this: `['4098AABC42B2', '-', 1, 28, true, '2021-07-08T11:07:47.634Z']`, and data has multiple rows.